# how can a media query detect a full-hd smartphone?

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

If a media query checks to see the number of pixels on the device,
How does it know between a desktop full hd monitor, and a full hd smartphone?

Obviously the design for both is very different (css-wise)..

Comment: what do you mean hd? are you trying to differentiate between retina and not retina?

Comment: Why would the design be different for a 1200px wide phone vs a 1200px desktop monitor?  If the answer is because the interface needs to be different for touch vs mouse, then CSS cannot help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do it by pixel density.

```
@media only screen (-moz-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), 
only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1), 
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), 
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
 /*This will be high ppi smart phone*/
}
```

Comment: working on mobile based Chrome(to some extent) but not with Firefox.
Could you provide with any rigid example. JSFiddle will also do.

Answer (score 0):

Media queries have no knowledge of desktop vs mobile browser. Your best bet is to use JS to analyze the user agent, or perform some feature tests.